# "generalised" scanl

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a sort of scanl like function of type:

```
general_scanl' :: (a->b->a)->(a->b->[c])->a->[b]->[c]
```

The function is intended to output the same as the following two monstrosities:

```
general_scanl' f g x y = snd $ foldl' (\(p,q) r -> (f p r,q ++ g p r)) (x,[]) y
```

or,

```
general_scanl' f g x y = concat $ zipWith g (scanl f x y) y
```

The disadvantage of the first definition is that it contains a handwritten lambda.
The disadvantage of the second definition is that it accumulates a list of lists (scanl f x y) which isn't necessary...

My question: **is there a cleaner way to define this function?**

Many thanks,

Comment: FYI `:t general_scanl' :: (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> b -> [c]) -> a -> [b] -> [c]`

Comment: Please fix either the types or the example functions (as MrBones pointed out), since we don't know currently what exactly you're asking for. Nevertheless, the second `general_scanl'` is fine and preferable to the first. The first is needlessly strict and will diverge if `y` is infinite. The second is lazy and just as fast.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I believe I've fixed the type now.

Comment: I'd have no objections against the second version. It's concise and I see accumulating a list of lists as an advantage, as calling `concat` at the end ensures that the sub-list are concatenated in _O(n)_. The first version has _O(n^2)_ time complexity because of appending an intermediate list to the end of the accumulated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
Prelude> let general_scanl2 f g z xs = concat $ zipWith g (scanl f z xs) xs
--                                                         :: [a]
Prelude> :t general_scanl2
general_scanl2 :: (a -> b -> a)        -- f
                  -> (a -> b -> [c])   -- g
                  -> a                 -- z
                  -> [b]               -- xs
                  -> [c]

Prelude Data.List> :t mapAccumL
mapAccumL :: (a -> b -> (a, y)) -> a -> [b] -> (a, [y])
```

So, another way to write this seems to be

```
import Data.List

g_scanl3 :: (a -> b -> a) -> (a -> b -> [c]) -> a -> [b] -> [c]
g_scanl3 f g z xs = concat . snd $ 
                      mapAccumL (\a b-> (f a b, g a b)) z xs
```

Comment: I'll look into your suggestion and the Arrow module. I'll accept the answer if satisfactory.  Thanks.

Comment: `Arrow` is used just for its `(&&&) f g x = (f x, g x)`.

Comment: mapAccumL is what I was after! I've also gotten curious about Arrows, thanks. Answer accepted.

Comment: I think I've erred. I fixed it, check it out. :)